# Numerical wildcard when using strcmp C/C++ for Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, wildcard, strcmp

I'm trying to compare two string with strcmp, for arduino.

I just wondered if there was a C/C++ /Arduino wild card for a number.

My input will be LP followed by 5 unknown digits.

E.g. something like

```
a_string[]="LP*****";

if( strcmp(input,a_sting) == 0 )
{
    // run this
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `strncmp()` to compare the first two characters?

Comment: Other input could start with LP but not be followed by digits

Comment: The `strcmp` function does not use wildcards.  You will have to use a regular expression function or maybe `isnum` function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Regex on **arduino** sounds like going to be a hard task achieving it :-P ...

Comment: @ThomasMatthews : Did you mean `isdigit()`?

Comment: I recommend 5 calls to `digit`.  probably a lot simpler than a regex function. And thanks @Clifford, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i,j,k,l,m;
if(strlen(input)==7 &&
   sscanf(input, "LP%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &i,&j,&k,&l,&m)==5)
{
    //run this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` won't do that.  `scanf()` will, do something close:

```
int i ;
if( scanf( "LP%d", &i) == 1 )
{
    printf( "match" ) ;
}
else
{
    printf( "no match" ) ;
}
```

But not specifically 5 digits.  The obvious solution is to use a *regular expression* library, but that might be a little heavyweight for Arduino and this simple requirement - it would be easy enough to write your own function to your specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that might suit your requirement very well, this code copies the first two letters from a[0] to a[1] . Furthermore, it then places a check to see if the letters entered were indeed L and P

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  char* a[2] ;
  int size = 7;
  a[0] = (void *) malloc( sizeof(char) * ( size + 1 ) );
  a[1] = (void *) malloc( sizeof(char) * 2 );
  printf("Enter device\n");
  fgets(a[0], 8, stdin);
  //strcpy( a[0], "LPC1768");
  puts(a[0]);
  printf("\n");
  //printf("a[0] = %s\n", a[0]);
  memcpy( a[1], a[0], 2 );
  if ( *(a[1]) == 'L' && *(a[1] + 1) == 'P')
  {
    puts(a[1]);
  }
free(a[0]);
free(a[1]);
}
```